# NoneType object is not callable when trying to redefine variable in while loop

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so maybe this is kind of a basic question. I'm writing a basic 2 person blackjack game. So the idea is to generate a deck of card at the beginning, play the games and if the user want to play again, begin the while loop all over again. I built a function to generate and shuffle a deck of cards like this:

```
import random

def deck():
    suites = ["Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"]
    names = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"J","Q","K","A"]
    deck = []
    for suite in suites:
        for name in names:
            deck.append((name,suite))
    return random.sample(deck,len(deck))
```

And then at the beginning of the game, I'd call a while True loop, play the game and then ask the user if they want to play again, like this:

```
while True:
        deck = deck()
# codes to play game here
userinput = input("Play again?")
    while not userinput.replace(" ", "") in ["yes","no"]:
        userinput = input("Play again?")    
    if userinput.replace(" ", "") == "no":
        break
    else:
            deck = None
            dealer_hand = None
            player_hand = None
            continue
```

I understand that assigning None to a variable in Python is a way to use it as a placeholder, like nothing, so that when the user choose "yes", and the continue statement is executed, the variable "deck" will be assigned to the return value of my function deck() defined earlier but when I tried to do that Python throw a NoneType is not callable. I come from VBA, and when the loop begins again, normally all variables that are assigned will take new values without issues so this is hard to understand for me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide the full code together?

Comment: You don't have a variable `deck` and a function `deck`. There's only a single `deck`.

Comment: What @melpomene said.  Change the variable to `_deck` or something.

Comment: Confirm that changing variable name did the job. I still have a hard time understanding why Python can't make the distinction between a variable (deck without the parentheses) and a function (deck() with parentheses). Isn't the parentheses enough for Python to make the distinction?

Answer (score 1):

> the variable "deck" will be assigned to the return value of my function deck() defined earlier

Yes, that's the problem. Once `deck = deck()` executes the first time, the function deck() will no longer be accessible in that scope. You have overridden its name. Python can't deduce that `deck()` means "find a function with the name deck, and call it". It will happily try to call any object you give it, including ones that don't make sense to call, like the list returned by `deck()`, or the None object you assign to `deck` in the `else` block.

Try using different names for your variable and function. I like to give functions names with verbs in them. How about `get_deck()`?

Comment: Deck is totally a verb: `deck(hall, holly.boughs)` :-)

Comment: Hmm, true. Ideally a function name would contain a word that is _only_ a verb. Since deck can be a noun or verb, there's an opportunity for ambiguity. No good.

Comment: Changing deck() to get_deck() did it. Can you elaborate more on why Python threw an error ? I thought having parentheses is enough for Python to distinguish between variables and functions.

Comment: All a pair of parentheses indicates is "hey Python, call this object". Not just functions can be called. Any object can be called. Granted, most objects will crash when you try because their class hasn't implemented `__call__`, but it's still syntactically valid to attempt it. Because any object has the potential to be called, Python does not give any kind of special status to functions in the name resolution system. When you assign a function's name to a new object, Python doesn't think "ok, but the old value was a function, so I'll hold on to it for later". It's just gone.